# Can Javascript and/or jQuery return objects this way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pulling a blank as to why this code isn't working as expected ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekStocks/ag3dd/)):

```
data = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 4.56
}, 
{
    "id": 2,
    "value": 7.89
}];


function FindMe(searchID) 
{
    $.each(data, function (i, v) 
    { 
        // i=index, v=value (which is an object)
        if (v.id === searchID) 
        {
            console.log("Found: ");
            console.log(v);
            return v; // pass the desired object back to caller
        }
    });
}

console.clear();
var test = FindMe(2); // causes the console to show the correct object
console.log("Returned: ");
console.log(test); // shows "undefined" instead of a returned object
```

The function clearly does its job to find the correct array element (the console shows this as "Found"), but the return isn't happening.  What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the looping function returns the found item, not the function FindMe.

Find me returns nothing.

```
function FindMe(searchID) {
 var result;    
    $.each(data, function (i, v) { // i=index, v=value (which is an object)
        if (v.id === searchID) {
            console.log("Found: ");
            console.log(v);
            result = v; // pass the desired object back to caller
            return false;
        }
    });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `FindMe` function has no `return` statement. You're just calling `$.each`...

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.each` just iterates, it does not collect. What you need is something similar to the native [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like [this one here](http://jsfiddle.net/ag3dd/12/):

```
function FindMe(searchID) {
    return data.filter(function(datum){
        return (datum.id === searchID);
    });
}
```

[Most browsers should have `Array.prototype.filter` by now, except <= IE8.](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
data = [{
"id": 1,
    "value": 4.56
}, {
    "id": 2,
        "value": 7.89
}];


function FindMe(searchID) {
     var searchObj=null;
    $.each(data, function (i, v) { // i=index, v=value (which is an object)
        if (v.id === searchID) {
            console.log("Found: ");
            console.log(v);
           searchObj = v; // pass the desired object back to   caller
            return false;
        }
    });
    return searchObj;
}

console.clear();
var test = FindMe(2); 
object
console.log("Returned: ");
console.log(test);
object
```